# SOLVED Three-Pin Switch for On/Off, Pi Zero W

Tags: gpio, switches

I'm a novice python coder, and even more novice pi user/electronics person. I'm trying to set up an on/off switch on my headless pi with a three-pin arcade switch I found. Right now the switch is plugged into GPIO 16 - GRND - GPIO 12. From googling, I ascertain that I can just write some code to watch for a voltage raise in GPIO 16 or 12 (*which one?*), and launch a shutdown script thereafter.

**Will I fry my board if I plug it in with this switch on the pins?** I specifically made sure not to plug it into any 3.3/5v pins, so I think I'm safe, but also don't want to buy a new board.

Answer (score 2):

The "one button ON-OFF" switch function has been built into the Raspberry Pi [**device tree**](https://www.devicetree.org/) since July, 2017. All that's really required is two pieces of wire, but a *momentary* push-button switch can be added if you wish - perhaps your "three pin switch" can serve in this role?

##### One Button?

Let me explain in the following schematic what is meant by "one button ON-OFF" function, as there has been some confusion on this point:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft1ghw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Two items of note:

1. While *no software is required* to implement the **one-button-ON/OFF** feature, the *device tree overlay* shown below must be added to the file `/boot/config.txt` (for `bullseye` & earlier), or the file `boot/firmware/config.txt` (for `bookworm` & later):

> at the command prompt, open the file for editing:

```
$ sudo nano /boot/config.txt              # bullseye & earlier 
# OR...
$ sudo nano /boot/firmware/config.txt     # bookworm & later
```

> once the file is open, add the following line of text:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown,gpio_pin=3
```

2. The RPi will cease processing in the "OFF" state, but will continue to draw power. As of this writing, reaching a "ZERO POWER" state for all RPi models may be achieved only by "pulling the plug".

##### Background

Matthijs Kooijman developed the `dtoverlay` for `gpio-shutdown`. His [blog post discusses his motivation, and provides some details: "Raspberry pi powerdown and powerup button"](https://www.stderr.nl/Blog/Hardware/RaspberryPi/PowerButton.html). If you're interested in the *source code* for this particular *dtoverlay*, you can find that [here in the RPi GitHub repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/pull/2103/commits/6cb4827afd84587011fe16e8d6dee87081faa8e6).

While the overlay allows the user to specify any GPIO, only GPIO 3 (the default) allows one to shutdown **and** startup using the same single  button. If the user selects a different GPIO, the user may shutdown the RPi, but a startup requires a power cycle - i.e. unplug the power cord & plug it in again. And finally, on the subject of power, know that the RPi will continue to draw power even after the shutdown. The power consumption will be *reduced, but not eliminated*.

Comment: Thank you for this extremely thoughtful and detailed comment. dtoverlay worked!

Comment: @Tooluser: Glad to hear it helped. The [conventions for voting and accepting answers are given here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers); please read & follow up as you see fit.